# Resources used by ExtendedEvents

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, extended-events

Does anyone know how to tell how many resources (CPU/MEM/Reads etc) have been used by SQL Server Extended Events?

I've went through the available DMVs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/extended-events-dynamic-management-views?view=sql-server-2017) 
But I dont see where this is tracked anywhere.

I'm asking b/c I worked on a poorly performing sql server for a few days before I realized there was an EE session running that, when killed, cut CPU utilization in half. (It was Idera Sql DM running the EE Session)

Answer (score 0):

It should be more of a case support with idera. Generally these are good repuatated products in market which have a better documentation than we can explain here. I can share this based on my experience with sentry support where had similar if not exact issue. E.g if you are using idera to collect actual execution plan or events for tracking queries and their metrics comes with additional cost.

Please open a case with idera and go through their documentation for further troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are indeed correct that I am pursing something with Idera. But you dont answer the question, how can I track resource usage for EE Sessions.